# change base path in blazor server application

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to change the base path in a Blazor server application. Instead of having it at
`http://localhost:5000/` I want to have it at `http://localhost:5000/CoolApp/`

I followed [this instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), but the application crashes with:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /CoolApp/{**path:nonfile}, area: }.

Here's [the sample](https://dev.azure.com/cmedianu0603/publicProject/_git/BlazorServerPathChangeSoln/commit/c6e135c91ed8f2430d6a6af208bac222500bffeb?refName=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster)

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. I explored it for about an hour or so as    well. The problem was that in my component I had a

`href="@($"/myPageComponent/{id}")"`

...When I removed the / and made it

`href="@($"myPageComponent/{id}")"`

then it worked. Basically, check your child's component and make sure    that you have no slash in the beginning. As the slash is saying "Go    to the root". Also, in my specific case, I had to include a separate    web.config file that prevented the app from inheriting parent    configuration features. Like So

```
`<configuration>
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
<configuration/>`
```

Answer (score -2):

You should removing the `app.PathBase()`:

```
app.Map("/CoolApp", coolApp =>
{
    coolApp.MapBlazorHub();
    coolApp.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

This will mean nothing will run unless it is on the `/CoolApp` endpoint - and you don't need to worry about appending the `/CoolApp` route to anything.

In future if you don't want the `/CoolApp` base path - move the inside of the `Map()` function out and remove it, replacing `coolApp` with `app`.

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: What is "You should removing the app.PathBase() ... Do you mean to say "You should remove the app.PathBase()."?